# 3D interpolation to 'm x n' matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, image-processing, interpolation

Let's consider an example:

Case 1:

```
rdata = Table[Sin[u + v^2] + RandomReal[], {u, 0, 3, .2}, {v, 0, 4, .2}];
w1 = ListPlot3D[rdata, Mesh -> All]
w2 = ListPlot3D[rdata, Mesh -> All, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 1}]
```

How on the basis of the set `rdata = {r1, r2, r3}`, determine the set `points` of the data `r3` (`points` is a matrix with the dimension $m \times n$) which can be seen in the figures `w1` and `w2`?

```
points =(* 'm x n' matrix *)

ReliefPlot[points, ColorFunction -> "GreenBrownTerrain"] (*?????*)
```

Case 2: (more important for me):

rdata = Table[{x = RandomReal[{0, 1}], y = Sin[RandomReal[{0, 1}]], Cos[RandomReal[]]/5}, {2000}];

...the remaining part as in the 'case 1'.

Comment: Hint: Use backticks (`) instead of (') for markup.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you ask for but if it is about interpolation, you can use `ListInterpolation` with an `InterpolationOrder` of your choice:

```
f = ListInterpolation[rdata, InterpolationOrder -> 3];
```

Now you can use as a function from the plane to the reals, e.g. `Map` it over other lists of points in the plane.

Here is a plot with the data points in order to show how the list gets interpolated:

```
{m, n} = Dimensions[rdata];
pts = Join[Outer[List, Range[m], Range[n]], Map[List, rdata, {2}], 3];
w0 = Graphics3D[Sphere[Flatten[pts, 1], 0.1]];
w3 = Plot3D[f[s, t], {s, 1, m}, {t, 1, n}, PlotPoints -> 5 {m, n}, Mesh -> {m - 2, n - 2}];
Show[w0, w3]
```

[image]

When interpolating 3D points that are supposed to lie one a graph, then `Interpolation` can be used. If the $(x,y)$-points do not live on a regular quad grid then only `InterpolationOrder->1` is supported. Note that the syntax `{{x,y},z}` has to be used.

```
n = 2000;
x = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n];
y = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n];
z = Sin[2 Pi x + Pi y]/5.;
rdata = Transpose[{Transpose[{x, y}], z}];
f = Interpolation[rdata, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

This interpolates the data over a triangle mesh, proabably the 2D-`DelaunayMesh`". This is how you can draw the resulting function:

```
R = DelaunayMesh[Transpose[{x, y}]];
Show[
 Graphics3D[Sphere[Flatten /@ rdata, 0.01]],
 Plot3D[f[s, t], {s, t} ∈ R, Mesh -> All]
 ]
```

[image]

While the interpolation in the interior parts of the domain deem to be good, be cautious when using the interpolating function `f` close to the boundary of the domain.

`ReliefPlot` also expects the height values to lie on a quad grid; you can generate such a grid and sample `f` over it to create data that `ReliefPlot` can eat:

```
m = 200;
n = 200;
heights = Apply[f,
   Outer[
    List,
    Subdivide[0.2, 0.8, m],
    Subdivide[0.2, 0.8, n]
    ], {2}];
ReliefPlot[heights, ColorFunction -> "GreenBrownTerrain"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. We can obtain the sought  set:  points= Split[Flatten[pts, 1], #1[[1]] == #2[[1]] &][[All,All,3]]; ....There is still a problem with 'Case 2'.

Comment: While earlier it was easy to generate a matrix 'm x n'  ('points') so now I do not know how to do it. I just have to use the ReliefPlot[] function to draw a set 'points'.